# Drupal 8 "Display settings" tab missing from all content types

Tags: drupal-8

On a certain Drupal 8 site (8.5.6), the "Display settings" tab is missing from the bottom vertical tabs of every content type. I must have deleted, disabled, uninstalled, or broken something. Have tried everything I can think of, but nothing helps. I have googled, checked documentation, compared to non-impaired sites, asked coworkers, etc. Many hours spent. Maybe missing something obvious. Suggestions for getting it back will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally discovered that installing the "Manage display" module (still in alpha at the time of this writing) is what removed the "Display settings" tab from the bottom vertical tabs of all content types. Seems to be intentional, although the alternative means of hiding authored-by and authored-on information supplied by the module ("Authored by" and "Authored on" fields added to each content type which can be dragged to the Disabled group) doesn't seem to work quite correctly for me.